# How to call image into reactjs and airtable

Tags: reactjs

Am using **airtable.com** helloworld sample code. my logo.jpg is in the same directory as the index.js files

```
myproject-folder\frontend\index.js
myproject-folder\frontend\logo.png
```

The airtable app is not using webpack so I could not import the logo image.

I have tried calling the image directly as per code
below but could not get it to work.

```
<img src={window.location.origin + './logo.jpg'} />
<img src={'./logo.jpg'} />
```

**here is the code**

```
import {
    initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component } from "react";



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello world from Airtable</h2>



<img src={'./logo.jpg'} />

        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are using webpack to build your app.

Webpack treat assets as dependencies. As such, you need to `import` your image and use an appropriate loader to handle the file type of your logo.

From [webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/):

> [...] When you import MyImage from './my-image.png', that image will
>   be processed and added to your output directory and the MyImage
>   variable will contain the final url of that image after processing.
>   [...] The loader will recognize this is a local file, and replace the
>   './my-image.png' path with the final path to the image in your output
>   directory.

In your case, you could do this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    initializeBlock,
    useBase,
    useRecords,
} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';

import logo from './logo.png';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Hello world from Airtable</h2>
                <img src={logo} />
            </div>
        );
    }
 }

 export default App;
```

You'd then need to add the `file-loader` to your webpack config file:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
        'file-loader',
    ],
},
```